# Showing facebook preview when US peers are blocked

Tags: facebook, ip

Due to our launch plan we have our site blocked outside of our country (private beta outside, public site here) so whenever a link is shared on facebook it shows the preview of the private beta instead of the one of the actual link. Is there a workaround this? Maybe giving access to the page to a certain range of IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Facebook collects the information that will be displayed, not the user. I'm pretty sure that Facebook just has US IPs and therefore there is no workaround for this, except just outputting non-private stuff...

Comment: Yeah, but I was wondering if facebook crawls from a determined set of IP addresses, so I could give access to those ones.